# Inspect kernelmanagerd log

Tags: cpu, logs, kernel-extensions

With BigSur, I have the notorious problem of the kernelmanagerd process constantly using a large part of the CPU (at least 35/40%).

so, following the various guides found online, I have:

- uninstalled Malwarebytes
- uninstalled Dropbox
- removed non-Apple kexts from /Library/Extensions

I have no other applications among those that are known to generate the problem.

I was wondering, is there a way to see the kernelmanagerd log, or at least a log that allows me to understand which application/extension generates the problem?

Comment: Did you find out what was causing those high spikes of CPU usage? I am still hunting down the same issue.

Comment: Hi Valerio, unfortunately not. I uninstalled everything I could and did a lot of clean-up as well. but the problem still. I also heard from apple (with Apple care) but they basically told me that I have to re-install the OS.